# Easiest way to make printing head spray ink?

Tags: signal

If I have a free-standing printing head including ink tanks, what would I have to do to just make it spray some ink? Are there some standardized signal encodings or something?

I'm not talking about generating an "output" with a moving head. Just a free head that should spray some droplets of ink.

And where would be a good starting point to find out more about such kind of knowledge?

Comment: How are you going to remove the ink if it does not transfer to paper and ends up clogging the jets?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that question. Remove the ink from where? I want to be able to spray a short "ink pulse" from the head (which is not connected to any printer anymore). Or do you mean what I'll do if the head is "polluted" by ink making it stop working? I'll just clean it, I think. Or is there a some reason speaking against that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A lot of that is proprietary but I've spent a lot of time reverse engineering print heads and building printers :)   Usually the firing voltage is high in the 24/30 V range.   If you just want it to spit you can usually drive some current through it at the appropriate voltage and get some ink to come out (I assume you have a resistive head and not a piezo most heads now a days are resistive).   I'd start by trying to just pulse some through it as you don't want to hook it up continuously and burn out the head.

Your just looking to get a short burst, heat up the tiny element behind the nozzle and get the ink to fire out.

Whose head are you using?

### Actually Printing

To actually print something takes more effort, we developed dedicated silicon just to do that.   But basically you convert the pixels or dots you want to print into high voltage firing pulses that activate each nozzle.  So usually the first step after spitting a blog of ink onto a page is to print out some test pattern by firing multiple nozzles.   You'll notice that there are a lot more nozzles than there are pins though :)  So to figure out the right sequence you'll need a scope or better yet a logic analyzer.

Printing and moving across a page or object?   That's a whole different story that will involve some encoders and control loops :)

Comment: I should add that you can usually get a head to work just using a bench top power supply and some wire.  Just make sure you're making momentary contact and not leaving the power on!

Comment: Thanks. I'm not having a specific head now. I'm just doing some brainstorming and information gathering. When I think I got enough informations I'll just get some old printer somewhere and try it out. Do you recommend a specific type of head that does best results?

Comment: Yes get the cheapest low end, older printer you can find from HP like this: http://www.hp.com/hpinfo/newsroom/recalls/fax1010.html  The lower the resolution and the older the head technology the easier it will be for you to get working.

Comment: Another tip it's best to check out the firing pulses first on a scope.  If you turn the head element on too long you just evaporate the ink, if don't turn it on enough then nothing comes out.  If you leave it on really long you'll burn it out.  It's pretty satisfying to get that ink to finally spit out onto some paper though so don't give up.

Comment: Thanks for all that imformation. :) Do you have a website where you share your experiences? Or know a website that does? Best with pictures.

Comment: +1 for "Whose head are you using?" - That deserves to go on a T-shirt :-) Very useful insight into the arcane arts of picoliter printing, thanks!

Comment: Thank you. I know this is an old post but still great insights, thus making my question here. Is it right to assume that the logic analyzer mentioned here is "in contact" with the pins of the printing head, and not talking about USB logging software(for printers that are connected via USB to the computer)? Or could both achieve the same - getting the signal waveform as an instruction to the printing head for jetting the ink out of the nozzle?

Comment: In this case I was referring to the pins on the printing head. You could think of the data coming over USB as the computer's printer driver telling the printer what to do.  Then the local electronics tell the head how to do it.